# if i checked parent checkbox all child check boxes will be checked in php while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

```
<?php
$cq=mysqli_query($db_con,"SELECT * FROM `course` WHERE `status`='1' ");
while($cf=mysqli_fetch_array($cq)){
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#parent<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>').on('click',function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $('#child<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>').prop('checked',true);
        }else{
            $('#child<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>').prop('checked',false);
        }
    });

});

</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" id="parent<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>"><?php echo $cf['course']; ?><br>

<?php
$sq=mysqli_query($db_con,"SELECT * FROM `softwares` WHERE `course`='$cf[id]' AND `status`='1' ");
while($sf=mysqli_fetch_array($sq)){
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="softwares[]" id="child<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>" class="cu"><?php echo $sf['software']; ?><br>

<?php }} ?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16k2N.png)

if i checked parent checkbox all child check boxes will be checked but only first child check box is checked

Comment: IDs must be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: Make your "child IDs" a `class` value instead of an `id` value and use a class selector to match them all.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `class` instead of `id` because, `id` is a unique element for every HTML and multiple elements can have same `class`.

So, children checkbox HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="softwares[]" id="child<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>" class="cu child<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>"><?php echo $sf['software']; ?><br>
```

And JS:

```
$('#parent<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>').on('click',function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $('.child<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>').prop('checked',true);
        }else{
            $('.child<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>').prop('checked',false);
        }
    });
```